# Pandas - Operate with series and delays

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe in Pandas. My doubt is how can I make to operate with series where one has a time delay. For example, I would like to calculate the result of dividing the GDP of a period by the population of the next period.

```
         GDP     Population
1950     3.31        1
1951     3.5         1
...
2000     15.2        2
```

Answer (score 4):

To do that you can just use:

```
df['new_col'] = df['GDP'] / df['Population'].shift(1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you consider using `shift`?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"GDP": np.random.normal(3,1,51),
                   "Pop":np.random.randint(1,10,51)},
                   index=np.arange(1950,2001))
df["res"] = df.GDP.shift(1)/df.Pop
```